# What is wrong with my strcmp function?

Tags: c

My code is:

```
getline(&cmd, &len, stdin);
cmd[strcspn(cmd,"\n")] = 0;
char *ncmd = (char*)malloc(strlen(cmd) + 1);
memset(ncmd, '\0', strlen(cmd));
strcpy(ncmd,cmd);

const char *tok = strtok(ncmd, " ");


// token is just string from stdin
if(!strcmp(tok, "bye")){
    printf("bye");
} else if (!strcmp(tok, "help")){
    printf("help");
} else if (!strcmp(tok, "list")){
    ......
}
```

ie. For input: help and bye

```
Result: TOK: help
        strcmp(tok, "bye"): 6
        strcmp(tok, "help"): 0
        strcmp(tok, "list"): -10

Result: TOK: bye
        strcmp(tok, "bye"): 0
        strcmp(tok, "help"): -6
        strcmp(tok, "list"): -4
```

Whatever I type, I can't seem to pull out the correct if statement.
How do I fix the "strcmp" function so it goes to the correct if statements?

Comment: So what is actually `tok`? And what it does? Show the full code please.

Comment: @EugeneSh. if I type  "help", tok is "help"

Comment: Are you sure? Show the reading code.

Comment: @KadanaKanz No, really - what does  `tok` contain ?. You need to double and triple check that it doesn't e.g. contain a newline, space or other non visible character. It would help if you show more code, e.g. how you read from stdin and into the `tok` variable.

Comment: Try printing `tok` with quotes, so that the output should be `"bye"` etc. That will allow you to spot extra characters, as in `"bye   "`.

Comment: It would be more reliable just to print `strlen` of it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. tried with strlen, length is equal to input

Comment: You need to post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem that you think you're having. The processing of `tok` is overkill, but you still haven't shown where the input is coming from. And the sample output a) doesn't match the code and b) is exactly what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code and `if` statement are correct, I think `tok` has extra characters, such as a newline. Then `tok` will never be equal to any of your words.

Comment: If this is the case, the solution would be to use `strncmp` variant.

Comment: I was going to say the same. I suspect a trailing newline is the problem. Either strip off the trailing whitespace, or use `strncmp` instead of `strcmp`.

Comment: I've removed the whitespace (updated code) and checked with strlen and inputs : help has length 4 etc. They all match so idk what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: edit: sorry just realised that the version I was compiling was searching a different string this fixed it :D

Answer (score 0):

When creating a buffer to use with `strtok()`, often times the same buffer will be used several times.  Therefore, instead of declaring it as:

```
const char *tok = strtok(ncmd, " "); //tok cannot be changed (const keyword)
```

Create it so it can be changed:

```
char *tok = strtok(ncmd, " ");//tok can be changed  (removed const keyword)
```

Example:

```
char string[] = {"this is \n a string \t with embedded \r non-printables"};
char *tok = {0};  //declare and initialize

tok = strtok(string, " \n\r\t");
while(tok)
{
    tok = strtok(NULL, " \n\r\t");//tok will be a different value each iteration  
    //   1 - this
    //   2 - is
    //   3 - a
    //   4 - string
    //   and so on 
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your code properly, but I hope this is what you are trying to achieve in your code:

```
int main()
{
    char list[] = "bye help list";
    char *delim = " ";
    char *pch = strtok(list,delim);
    int count = 0;
    while(pch) {
        if(!strcmp(pch,"bye")) {
            printf("i found bye at %d\n",count);
        } else if (!strcmp(pch,"help")) {
            printf("i found help at %d\n",count);
        } else if (!strcmp(pch,"list")) {
            printf("i found list at %d",count);
        }
        count++;
        pch = strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```